# Use output of one statement as input for another (recursively)

Tags: sql, postgresql

The `product` table is associated to the `categories` table via `product.ext_category_id=categories.ext_id`, however the `ext_category_id` might be associated to either a level 1, level 2, or level 3 category within the `categories` table.

I'm looking for a select statement that will select all of the products in the products table as well as the corresponding level 1 category from the category table.

| product.id | product.product_name | categories.name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Strawberries | Fruit & Vegetable department |
| 2 | Bananas | Fruit & Vegetable department |
| 3 | Potatoes | Fruit & Vegetable department |
| 4 | Car Battery | Automotive department |
| 5 | Chips | Junk Food department |

If a product from the `products` table is associated to either a level 2 or level 3 category within the `categories` table, then you need to use the `categories.parent_id` to search the `categories.id` column within the `categories` table to find the next category, until you get the level 1 category.

I've spent a day trying to figure this out using various methods such as CASE and subqueries with the select statement, and recursive functions, but nothing worked. Sample CASE snippet -

```
SELECT
    product.id,
    product.product_name,
    CASE WHEN categories.level = '3' THEN (
           SELECT c2.name
           FROM categories c2
           WHERE c2.id = categories.parent_id )
    END AS level_2_cat_name
FROM product
    JOIN categories ON categories.ext_id = product.ext_category_id
```

Example `product` Table

| id | product_name | ext_category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Strawberries | 101 |
| 2 | Bananas | 102 |
| 3 | Potatoes | 103 |
| 4 | Car Battery | 104 |
| 5 | Chips | 105 |

Example `categories` Table

| id | ext_id | name | level | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 101 | Fruit | 2 | 2000 |
| 1002 | 102 | Fruit | 2 | 2000 |
| 1003 | 103 | Vegetables | 2 | 2000 |
| 1004 | 104 | Car Parts | 3 | 2500 |
| 2001 | 209 | Junk Food Department | 1 | Null |

...

| id | ext_id | name | level | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 205 | Fruit & Vegetable department | 1 | Null |
| 2000 | 205 | Fruit & Vegetable department | 1 | Null |
| 2000 | 205 | Fruit & Vegetable department | 1 | Null |
| 2500 | 309 | Cars & Trucks | 2 | 2002 |
| 2002 | 209 | Automotive department | 1 | Null |
| 2001 | 209 | Junk Food department | 1 | Null |

Comment: One approach would be to walk the category table recursively first, to derive the pairs, and then join this result with the product table.  But you could also use the product table to determine the start/root in the category to begin the walk.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately I'm fairly new to complex queries such as what you suggested (at least it seems complex to me?). Any way you could provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using Recursive CTE to solve the problem.
This will handle practically any number of category levels.

There are a few ways to do this.

Your test data had some mistakes.  I've corrected them for this test.

Note: There was an outer join, because your initial data didn't have a matching category related to Chips.  That can be removed if there is no missing data.  I'm going to remove it now.

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3251e71d4a9a529dd8b656329ac98866)

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 (id, name, cid, cname, level, parent_id) AS (
        SELECT p.id, p.product_name, c.id, c.name, level, parent_id
          FROM product     AS p
          JOIN categories  AS c
            ON p.ext_category_id = c.ext_id
         UNION ALL
        SELECT p.id, p.name, c.id AS cid, c.name AS cname, c.level, c.parent_id
          FROM cte1        AS p
          JOIN categories  AS c
            ON c.id = p.parent_id
     )
SELECT id, name, cname
  FROM cte1
 WHERE level = 1
 ORDER BY id
;
```

The result:

```
+------+--------------+------------------------------+
| id   | name         | cname                        |
+------+--------------+------------------------------+
|    1 | Strawberries | Fruit & Vegetable department |
|    2 | Bananas      | Fruit & Vegetable department |
|    3 | Potatoes     | Fruit & Vegetable department |
|    4 | Car Battery  | Automotive department        |
|    5 | Chips        | Junk Food Department         |
+------+--------------+------------------------------+
```

The setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product (
    id               int
  , product_name     varchar(40)
  , ext_category_id  int
);

INSERT INTO product VALUES
  ( 1, 'Strawberries' , 101)
, ( 2, 'Bananas'      , 102)
, ( 3, 'Potatoes'     , 103)
, ( 4, 'Car Battery'  , 104)
, ( 5, 'Chips'        , 105)
;

CREATE TABLE categories (
    id           int
  , ext_id       int
  , name         varchar(40)
  , level        int
  , parent_id    int
);

-- id   ext_id  name    level   parent_id
INSERT INTO categories VALUES
  (1001, 101, 'Fruit'                , 2, 2000)
, (1002, 102, 'Fruit'                , 2, 2000)
, (1003, 103, 'Vegetables'           , 2, 2000)
, (1004, 104, 'Car Parts'            , 3, 2500)
, (1005, 105, 'FoodParts'            , 2, 2001)
, (2001, 209, 'Junk Food Department' , 1, Null)
, (2000, 205, 'Fruit & Vegetable department', 1, Null)
, (2500, 309, 'Cars & Trucks'               , 2, 2002)
, (2002, 209, 'Automotive department'       , 1, Null)
;
```